# Login with PayPal (PHP) -> 'Credential not found for default user.'

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I always get the following error when I want to login with PayPal:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalInvalidCredentialException' with message 'Credential not found for default user. Please make sure your configuration/APIContext has credential information' in /home/.sites/137/site1611/web/Website/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalCredentialManager.php:154
```

I implemented the PayPal PHP SDK correctly and I already created a Sandbox User account in my PayPal developer dashboard. I also retrieve a correct `refresh_token` and `access_token` but I'm not able to retrieve the user information like email, name, etc. What am I doing wrong?

My JS on the 'Login with PayPal' page looks like that:

```
<span id="myContainer" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1000;"></span>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
<script>
        paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
          login.render ({
            "appid": "ATAoL...nifIi",
            "authend": "sandbox",
            "scopes": "profile email address https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
            "containerid": "myContainer",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "returnurl": "http://www.url.com/return.php"
          });
        });
</script>
```

And my PHP script at the `returnurl` looks like that:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Api\OpenIdTokeninfo;
use PayPal\Api\OpenIdUserinfo;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;

$code = $_GET['code'];
$clientId = 'ATAoLjBG....AbL4vWj89y89nifIi';
$clientSecret = 'EKoaU4uh....YXwCjlCj6FadrRXAdx';

$apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($clientId, $clientSecret));

try {
  $accessToken = OpenIdTokeninfo::createFromAuthorizationCode(array('code' => $code), null, null, $apiContext);
}
catch (PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  print_r('###################### Error'); exit(1);
}

print_r('###################### Success: ' . $accessToken);

$user = OpenIdUserinfo::getUserinfo(array('access_token' => $accessToken, $apiContext));
print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last line, you are passing apicontext inside array by mistake ! Fix that and you should be fine.

You can see the sample code here: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/lipp/GetUserInfo.html

This is how it should be :

```
$user = OpenIdUserinfo::getUserinfo(array('access_token' => $accessToken), $apiContext);
print_r($user);
```